# Fragments overlap when using actionbar and bottom navigation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to create an app using bottom navigation.
Layouts and MainActivity was automatically created by Android studio, I've now added an icon in actionbar, when the icon is pressed a new fragment should appear and display the settings.
The problem is that the settings fragment overlap with fragments of bottom navigation (see images)

[image: Settings fragment overlap with one of other fragment used in bottom navigation]
[image: This should be how the settings fragment should be seen (here no overlap because notification fragment is curently void)]
In **first** image settings fragment overlap with one of other fragment used in bottom navigation. In **second** this should be how the settings fragment should be seen (here no overlap because notification fragment is curently void)

To add the settings icon on actionbar I used the onCreateOptionsMenu() method, here is the code of my MainActivity class:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Client client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);

        this.client = null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbar_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            setFragment();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void setFragment() {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        ft.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new SettingsFragment());
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Can someone help me solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Give background color to rootview of your fragment layout

Comment: Doing so it will just cover objects displayed but they will still be clickable, so this is not a viable way

Comment: add clickable = true for your root viewgroup in fragment, this solves your issues